# How to set Google Drive folders to public after latest change

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

Up until fairly recently there was a straightforward easy to find option in the share or get link settings that had a straight up 'public' settings for Google Drive folders.

Does anyone know the current way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

#### How to share a Google folder/file.

Please have a look at the following screenshots.

#### Step 1.

Right click on the folder/file.

[image]

#### Step 2.

Finalize your choice.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).